# Как нужно настроить базу данных MySql для локального подключения

Tags: c#, mysql, база-данных, winforms, сервер

В WinForms разработана программа, в которую входит тест для прохождения учениками. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы результаты тестов с компьютеров учеников отправлялись в базу данных на компьютере учителя,все компьютеры подключены по локальной сети.

Что именно следует настроить для доступности подключения? Используется MySql

Comment: «базу данных» — никак. «сервер баз данных» — можно, но не нужно. правильнее — отправлять информацию с клиентов серверной программе (да, можете её написать хоть на c#). а серверная программа уже будет заносить информацию в базу данных, обращаясь к серверу баз данных.

Comment: Если отбросить в сторону вопросы безопасности БД, то надо настроить на каком адресе сервер MySQL будет слушать входящие запросы, по умолчанию localhost. А если по нормальному делать, то нужен отдельный сервис, который живет рядом с БД и обрабатывает запросы клиентов, но для этого придется переписывать клиентскую программу и писать соответствующий сервис